# Why does Community votes to close as dupe?

Tags: support, duplicates

This [Question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/240825/multiplying-numbers) was closed as a dupe by Community and pxeger, but why Community and how did Community know?

[Revisions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/240825/revisions)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The challenge author voted to closed it as a dupe

See this MSE post: [New UI encourages askers to confirm or dispute duplicate votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250981/355458)

Essentially, when a user votes to close a question as a duplicate, the author is shown a pop-up that says, roughly:

> This question may already have an answer here:
> [link to potential duplicate]

and they are asked to decide if that question is indeed a duplicate. If they click yes, they instantly close the question as a duplicate, and the vote is attributed to the [Community user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community).

Note that if you hover your mouse over the Community user's name, it provides a helpful tooltip:

[image: screenshot of the "question closed" box, with a tooltip from hovering over the Community user, saying "This question's author approved a pending duplicate vote"]